# Mongodb Join having nested arrays and objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, join, mongodb-query

If I have a data like that in collection 1, Like nested array and object and then I have another collectoin with objects.
How can I join these two collections and get the output as complete object with id,full name, its manager and depeartment for each seperate id. I have tried with unwind but i can't get to each single nested manager name and Id as i think if I can't get each single one of it, how can I join it with other collection id.
How can I join these? Also, is this even possible?

```
--Collection 1 {
        "ïd": 1,
        "name": "Max ",
        "managers": [{
                "ïd": 2,
                "name": "Caroline "
            },
            {
                "ïd": 3,
                "name": "Cecilia ",
                "managers": [{
                        "ïd": 4,
                        "name": "Geraldine ",
                        "managers": [{
                                "ïd": 5,
                                "name": "Ingrid "
                            },
                            {
                                "ïd": 6,
                                "name": "Jacqueline "
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ïd": 7,
                        "name": "Johannes "
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    --Collection 2
        [{
            "ïd": 1,
            "fullName": "Max Born",
            "department": "Management"
        }, {
            "ïd": 2,
            "fullName": "Caroline Herschel",
            "department": "Management"
        }, {
            "ïd": 3,
            "fullName": "Cecilia Payne-Gaposchkin",
            "department": "Management"
        }, {
            "ïd": 4,
            "fullName": "Geraldine Seydoux",
            "department": "Sales"
        }, {
            "ïd": 5,
            "fullName": "Ingrid Daubechies",
            "department": "Sales"
        }, {
            "ïd": 6,
            "fullName": "Jacqueline K. Barton",
            "department": "Sales"
        }, {
            "ïd": 7,
            "fullName": "Johannes Kepler",
            "department": "Application Development"
        }]
```

My expected output is like

```
{
            "ïd": 1,
            "name": "Max ",
            "fullName": "Max Born",
            "department": "Management"
},
{            "ïd": 2,
             "name": "Caroline ",
             "fullName": "Caroline Herschel",
             "department": "Management"
}
..... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [working code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/352D7ruh_PW) for your reference.

The basic idea is:

1. use `$lookup` to find fullName and department
2. use `$zip` to combine the original managers array and the looked up array
3. "flatten" the combined result
4. repeat steps 1-3 for different layers

However, despite being possible, the query is quite complex and I consider it being over-engineering. I would suggest you refactor your collection structure for easier processing.

-- edit

[New Mongo playgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1jyJvYUG0ip) as required by OP to flatten the result.

Comment: Your working is quite helpful. you are quite close. I have edited my post with my expected output maybe it help in understanding the use case.

Comment: Added another playground link to flatten the result as requested by you. I would like to restate the importance of remodel/restructure your collection.